# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutInterceptors "@OutInterceptors" disable on prod environment

Tags: java, spring

I am in situation, where we need to disable `@OutInterceptors` certain regions. Here is my scenario, i am inserting SOAP Req & Res xml payloads into table via `@OutInterceptors`. On prod environment, there will be high volume, at that time getting performance issue.  Thinking to turn-off on production environments.

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
-Som

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to disable/ turn-off {@OutInterceptors} depending on environment.?